# I want to transfert my data from editor.js to mongodb atlas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, text-editor

Hi want to send my data to mongodb, but my blocks aren't able to go to my database. The data came from editor.js

Those are my schema :

```
    const dataBlockSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
})

const BlockSchema = new Schema({
  type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  data: [dataBlockSchema],
});
const EditorSchema = new Schema({
  time: Number,
  blocks: [BlockSchema],
  version: String
});
const EditorModel = mongoose.model('Editor', EditorSchema);
```

This is my function to post my data :

```
async function post_data(outputData) {
    console.log('outputData:', outputData.blocks[0]);  // Log outputData for debugging
    try {
        let options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                blocks: outputData.blocks,
                time: outputData.time,
                version: outputData.version,
            }),
        };
        const resp = await fetch(URL, options);
        const data = await resp.json();

        console.log('Server response:', resp);  // Log server response for debugging

    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the server side code responsible for handling the request and sending the data to MongoDB? What output or response are you getting from the server? What does the server log?